# puppet - best way to collect data from custom types to be used in templates

Tags: puppet

I have following manifest:

```
define foo($var) {
    file { $var: }
    $barclass::store += $var
}

class barclass {
    $store = []
    foo {
        "test1": var => "test1",
        "test2": var => "test2",
    }

    file { "myfile": content => template("puppet:///files/myfile.erb"); }
}
```

And following erb template:

```
<% store.each { |i| -%> 
<%= i + " " -%> 
<% } -%>
```

My intention here is to collect all *$var* variables used as parameter of type *foo*. And provide them in *myfile.erb* template. In my example *$store* variable was used.

This example does not work. What have I wrong?

Is there better way to achieve same thing? I basically need to collect parameters used in some type and then provide them in some template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access variables set in puppet manifests directly (only facter facts) - what you need is scope.lookupvar

```
scope.lookupvar('yourmodulename::barclass::store')
```

or just

```
scope.lookupvar('barclass::store')
```

if it's not a module

SO

```
<% scope.lookupvar('barclass::store').each { |i| -%> 
<%= i + " " -%> 
<% } -%>
```